# Typecasting objects to a structure type in c#

Tags: c#, casting

I am porting managed C++ code to C#. I am trying to convert a piece of code where the function parameter is a byte array but then within the function body, it is typecasted to a structure pointer and used throughout the function.

How do you typecast a native data type to a structure in c# without having to use unsafe/pointers?

Code:

```
public byte[]   Mail( byte[]  mailbox, byte[] sst )
{
    pin_ptr<unsigned char>  header  =   &mailbox[0];
    PCMP_MAIL_HEADER        pHeader =   (PCMP_MAIL_HEADER)mailbox;
    int BodySize = (int) pHeader.MailLength;
    ...
}
```

PCMP_MAIL_HEADER is the user defined strucutre. I need to typecast mailbox to that structure.

Comment: You can use [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) if you don't want to pin it with `unsafe`.  You probably want [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146625.aspx)